# How do I fix a "[SQL0104] Token CODEUNITS32 was not valid. Valid tokens: OCTETS." error, in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, psql

I have a Spring Component class which calls a @Repository bean method in order to populate a list with these custom beans:

```
List<BeanTypeForList> beans = repoInstance.getDataForJurisdiction(jurisdiction);
```

This line returns this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement [[SQL0104] Token CODEUNITS32 was not valid. Valid tokens: OCTETS.] [select u1_0.STAT,u1_0.ACCT,u1_0.NAME,u2_0.ULADD1 from RT47G.UST u1_0,RT47G.LOCINF u2_0 where u1_0.ACCT=u2_0.LACT and substring(u1_0.ACCT,1,2,codeunits32)=? order by u1_0.ACCT]; SQL [select u1_0.STAT,u1_0.ACCT,u1_0.NAME,u2_0.ULADD1 from RT47G.UST u1_0,RT47G.LOCINF u2_0 where u1_0.ACCT=u2_0.LACT and substring(u1_0.ACCT,1,2,codeunits32)=? order by u1_0.ACCT]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:193) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:100) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-orm-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy135.getAccountLocationsForJurisdiction(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.company.dept.reports.processors.SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.populateAccountsPage(SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.java:710) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.company.dept.reports.processors.SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.populatePages(SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.java:462) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.company.dept.reports.processors.SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.buildAndPostWorksheet(SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.java:126) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.company.dept.reports.processors.SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.doWork(SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor.java:114) ~[classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
        at com.company.dept.reports.processors.SanitationWorksheetMakerProcessor$$SpringCGLIB$$0.doWork(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
        at com.company.dept.reports.runner.SanitationWorksheetRunner.run(SanitationWorksheetRunner.java:31) ~[classes!/:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar!/:3.0.6]
        ... 12 more
```

So from that, it looks like Spring JPA is inserting info into my Repository custom query, specifically here:`substring(u1_0.UCACCT,1,2,codeunits32)=?`

Whereas the query is:

```
    @Query(value = "select new com.company.dept.beans.reports.CustomerServiceLocationReportBean ("
            + "c.customerStatus, c.accountNumber, c.customerName, l.streetAddress911) "
            + "from UtilityCustomer c, UtilityAccountLocation l "
            + "where c.accountNumber = l.lastAccountNumber "
            + "and SUBSTRING(c.accountNumber,1,2) = :jurisdiction "
            + "order by c.accountNumber")
    List<CustomerServiceLocationReportBean> getDataForJurisdiction(@Param("jurisdiction") String jurisdiction);
```

So it's kind of seems like Spring is inserting "codeunits32" into this substring function for some reason, and that is not recognized as valid input when the query is executed.

The line with the substring function should just check to see if the first character in the account number field matches the given jurisdiction value.

When I remove the line with the substring function from the query, it runs successfully (besides not getting the data I want).

I am accessing this same DB table elsewhere and it gives no errors, although that method has no Substring method use, so I'm fairly sure it isn't a database issue.

I've tried `SUBSTRING(c.accountNumber,2,4) = :jurisdiction` and other variations on the index and string length but the same error is thrown.